# Simplifying this Python code for RPG levels

Tags: python

I am making a simple RPG game where Characters level based on experience (represented by x in the code below) in an exponential fashion. The levels only go up to Level 10, but I am confused what to do if their experience falls in-between the exponential numbers- 
I wrote this code below to round their Levels down to the lowest experience level, but is there a way to make this code simpler or more efficient?

```
  if 2<x<4:
        level=1
    if 4<x<8:
        level=2
    if 8<x<16:
        level=3
    if 16<x<32:
        level=4
    if 32<x<64:
        level=5
    if 64<x<128:
        level=6
    if 128<x<256:
        level=7
    if 256<x<512:
        level=8
    if 512<x<1024:
        level=9
    if x>1024:
        level=10
    print (level)
```

Comment: a lot of `elif` would have been better than a lot of `if`

Comment: You have a problem with "edge cases" as well. If `x == 8`, what is `level` then?

Comment: @Hannes +1, same for every pow of 2

Comment: `level = len(bin(x)) - 3`

Comment: The question is a little misleading- if 'x' falls into one of the "edge cases" [like 2,4,8,16,32,etc.] a part of the code before this takes care of these cases: this code only functions if x is not an edge case

Comment: Just for fun: You can easily build a list (or `array.array('B')`) of 1024 values at startup, and then you just index that list (`except IndexError: return 10`). This would almost certainly be a stupid thing to do in Python, but I did once find it very useful in C for a platform without hardware FP…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from math import log

...

level = int(log(x, 2))
level = min(level, 10) # as suggested by Morb
print(level)
```

Comment: if `x` is `6000` then your code will output `12`, but OP stated, that level can not go beyond `10`

Comment: `level = min(level, 10)` can help here

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937553/simplifying-this-python-code-for-rpg-levels/29937796#comment47996728_29937553) and [abarnert's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937553/simplifying-this-python-code-for-rpg-levels#comment47997033_29937796) suggestions

```
level = min(x.bit_length()) - 1, 10)
```

Comment: Using `len(bin(x))` is really an obtuse way to compute a logarithm. Why not just use `log`? (Or the `bit_length` method, maybe.)

Comment: Because I forgot about `bit_length` :)

Comment: OK, but what about `log`, which is the most obvious way to take a logarithm, and already had an answer before you wrote this one?

Comment: surely computing a logarithm is much more expensive?

Comment: `bin` and `bit_length` should be as fast as `log` approach, but they do not require imports. Also the other answer wasn't correct when I posted mine.

Answer (score 1):

We want to compute what is essentially floor(log_base_2(x)). Since integers are stored in binary format, their bits correspond to powers of 2. So one way to compute the level is to count the number of right-bitshifts it takes for our number to become 1. Note that a right-bitshift is essentially the same as dividing an integer by 2 and ignoring the remainder.

```
x_ = x
level = 0
while x_ > 1 and level < 10:
    x_ >>= 1
    level += 1
```

Comment: @Downvoters, I'd like to know how this answer can be improved.

Comment: You could explain your solution